# Grails 3.2 - object version doesn't update

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails3.2.0

Here is simple structure:

```
class Dom1 {
  /* some props */
  Dom2 dom2
}
class Dom2 {
  /* some props */
}
```

Let's say a dom2 object has been initialized.
If i create dom1 object like this:

```
def dom1 = new Dom1(dom2: dom2).save(flush:true)
```

i've got dom1 with version=0;
But after regetting dom1 from DB like:

```
dom1 = Dom1.get(dom1.id)
```

i've got dom1 with version=1.

DB record has version=1 too.
**Before upgrading from Grails 3.1 to 3.2 the problem doesn't exist.**

Is anyone know how to fix it? Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last Grails 3.2.6 has no this issue.